# How to pull SNMP information from Windows commandline without installing software

Tags: net-snmp

I would like to be able to quickly pull SNMP information via commandline such as device uptime.  I noticed Net-SNMP's snmpget.exe can do this; but it looks like I need to install Net-SNMP first before I can use that executable.

Isn't there any way to make this executable portable?  When I simply copy it to another machine and try to execute it, it complains that netsnmp.dll is missing.  If I copy that file to the same folder, it still says the file is missing.  I even tried to regsvr32 that dll, but I was unsuccessful.

Maybe there's a better way to get simple SNMP information from the Windows command line using royalty free/non-commercial software?

Edit:  It looks like I may be able to answer my own question.

http://www.snmpsoft.com/freetools/snmpget.html "SNMPGet.exe"

Comment: So, you're not willing to install software... you do realise that SNMPGet.exe counts as software, and that you need to install it before you can use it... right?

Answer (score 7):

Windows does not come with a default SNMP client, so you would *have* to install software. I recommend the `Net-SNMP` suite.

http://www.net-snmp.org/

Comment: You should provide a URL for Net-SNMP, so people don't go to a random site that is pretending to provide the same content